# Express Nodemailer in nuxt serverMiddleware - Error: spawn /usr/sbin/sendmail ENOENT

Tags: express, sendmail, nodemailer, nuxt.js

I'm trying to send a simple `POST` request for a contact form in a static site built on top of NuxtJs.

Im trying to use `express` and `nodemailer` in the `serverMiddleware` [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-servermiddleware/) provides

here's the code from `api/contact.js`

```
const express = require('express')
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const validator = require('validator')
const xssFilters = require('xss-filters')

const app = express()
app.use(express.json())

const rejectFunctions = new Map([
  ['name', a => a.trim().length < 4],
  ['email', v => !validator.isEmail(v)],
  ['message', v => v.trim().length < 10]
])

const validateAndSanitize = (key, value) => {
  return (
    rejectFunctions.has(key) &&
    !rejectFunctions.get(key)(value) &&
    xssFilters.inHTMLData(value)
  )
}

const sendMail = (name, email, msg) => {
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    sendmail: true,
    newline: 'unix',
    path: '/usr/sbin/sendmail'
  })
  transporter.sendMail(
    {
      from: email,
      to: 'johndoe@mail.com',
      subject: 'New Contact Form',
      text: msg
    }
  )
}

app.post('/', (req, res) => {

  const attributes = ['name', 'email', 'message']
  const sanitizedAttributes = attributes.map(attr =>
    validateAndSanitize(attr, req.body[attr])
  )

  const someInvalid = sanitizedAttributes.some(r => !r)

  if (someInvalid) {
    return res
      .status(422)
      .json({ error: 'Error : at least one fiel is invalid' })
  }

  sendMail(...sanitizedAttributes)

  res.status(200).json({ message: 'OH YEAH' })
})

export default {
  path: '/api/contact',
  handler: app
}
```

Everything works as intended until the `sendMail` function where I end up with this error :

```
(node:10266) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: spawn /usr/sbin/sendmail ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:427:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17)
(node:10266) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 6)
```

Any idea what Im doing wrong?

Comment: Is sendmail binary/program available at the configured path?  What is reported by `ls -l /usr/sbin/sendmail`?

Comment: Did you ever make any progress on this? It looks like maybe you used this walkthrough? https://blog.lichter.io/posts/emails-through-nuxtjs/ - I'm encountering the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
Error: spawn /usr/sbin/sendmail ENOENT
```

suggests that nodemailer was looking for `sendmail` in `/usr/sbin/` but haven't found it (this is the default location and can be configured in the `path` option of `createTransport`). First, make sure it doesn't exist (like AnFi has suggested) by running

```
ls -l /usr/sbin/sendmail
```

If you get

```
ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/sendmail': No such file or directory
```

then install `sendmail` by running

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

Then, try `ls -l /usr/sbin/sendmail` and sending email again.